# Nested agregate function in sql

Tags: sql, aggregate

I would like to ask if there is any DBMS that allow nested aggregate function similar to this one ??

```
Select max (avg(salary)) 
from employe 
group by employe.departement
```

Thank you.

Comment: What would that return? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.)

Comment: @Jarlh it should return  the best paid departement, (drpartement with the bigest  avg(salary), ) , but my question is it is possible to have an agregate function inside another one , and if yes what DBMS  allow that ??

Comment: `avg(salary) ... group by department` returns one row per department. Applying `max()` to that would still work "per department" and thus - even if the syntax was valid - it would return the average again.

Comment: Oracle allows this syntax.  I am not a fan.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , I try it  on Oracle it does not works ??

Comment: @IsmBlk . . . https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=35fe91a61d1442fed63b4d9a9cf670f1.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can do it with the next SQL query:

```
select department,
       avg(salary) as avg_salary
  from employee
 group by employee.departement
 order by avg_salary desc
 limit 1, 1;
```

The Oracle version is:

```
select department,
       avg(salary) as avg_salary
  from employee
 group by departement
 order by avg_salary desc
 fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Well Kapitany, i was not looking for an alternative to that query; but just trying to know if there is any DBMS that allow that syntax?

Answer (score -1):

you cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate in itself.

Comment: a question similar to this was asked in sql exam  the professors typical  answere was similar to that in the post , according to you i should claim a mistake in the profesdor answere ??